# How to get first record from lookup table that is a substring of some value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, substring, vlookup, countif

In MS-EXCEL, how can I achieve something like below:

```
Given:
sheet1 - raw-info ('james brown england', 'tommy australia 1234', 'saka ireland', 'denmark martin')
sheet2 - countries (england, nigeria, usa, denmark, australia)
```

after applying some formula, I want a new column in sheet1 that will have the following values:

```
sheet1 with two columns:
raw-info ('james brown england', 'tommy australia 1234', 'saka ireland', 'denmark martin')
new-col (england, australia, **blank**, denmark)
```

logic is:
if `raw-info` column value contains any value in `countries` column as a substring, use the matching value from `countries` column, else leave it blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In B2(assuming you have headers):

```
=INDEX('Sheet2'!A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW('Sheet2'!$A$1:$A$6)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Sheet2'!$A$1:$A$6,B2))),1))
```

Comment: you are excel God!